# How to plot a subset of a dataframe using ggplot2 in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, syntax-error, shiny-server

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mOBYkqqtoltX4kLC1zSyP3S34OK6NN-mCu_rUQydYjM/edit?usp=sharing - EuropeIndia data

My data set has 45 different countries in a variable called location I am trying to subset the data to each country and plot a scatter plot for each country
when I run the app the graph doesn't appear and I get 2 warnings

warning 1: The select input "location" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.
warning 2:"Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
102: cat"
here is the code I used please let me know where I am going wrong, thanks in advance

```html
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#


library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
covid <- read.csv("D:/R/Practice 3/EuropeIndia.csv")

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Deaths vs all variables "),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("location", "Select a country",
                  choices = covid$location), selected = NULL),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("location"),
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("cases",plotOutput("plot1t"), plotOutput("plot1n")),
        tabPanel("vaccinations",plotOutput("plot2t"), plotOutput("plot2n")),
        tabPanel("people",plotOutput("plot3t"),plotOutput("plot3n")),
        tabPanel("full vaccination",plotOutput("plot4t"), plotOutput("plot4n")),
        tabPanel("boosters",plotOutput("plot5t"), plotOutput("plot5n")),
        tabPanel("new vaccination",plotOutput("plot6t"),plotOutput("plot6n")),
        tabPanel("median age",plotOutput("plot7t"),plotOutput("plot7n")),
        tabPanel("new cases",plotOutput("plot8t"), plotOutput("plot8n")),
        tabPanel("summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
        tabPanel("dataset", tableOutput("dataset"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$location <- renderText({
    locationfilter <- subset(covid, covid$location == input$location)
  })
  output$plot1t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=total_cases))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot1n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=total_cases))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot2t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=total_vaccinations,color =location))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot2n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=total_vaccinations))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot3t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=people_vaccinated))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot3n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=people_vaccinated))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot4t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=people_fully_vaccinated))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot4n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=people_fully_vaccinated))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot5t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=total_boosters))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot5n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=total_boosters))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot6t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=new_vaccinations))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot6n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=new_vaccinations))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot7t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=median_age))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot7n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=median_age))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot8t <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=total_deaths,x=new_cases))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$plot8n <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(covid[covid$total_cases %in% "A", ],aes(y=new_deaths,x=new_cases))+geom_point()
    
  })
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(covid)
  })
  output$dataset <- renderTable({
    covid
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: hi, please provide an example we can reproduce:  covid <- read.csv("D:/R/Practice 3/EuropeIndia.csv") we dont have this file, so we cant run your code

Comment: I will try adding the dataset to this question

Answer (score 0):

When using `selectInput()` try *only including the unique options* in the `choices` argument. Also I think you had the `selected = NULL` in the wrong brackets but I'm not sure if that would have actually caused any issues.

```
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("location", "Select a country",
              choices = unique(covid$location), selected = NULL))
```

Comment: Oh I will check into it but the actual problem is I am not able to produce the graphs

Comment: As yuliaUU pointed out in the comments we can't diagnose the actual problem because you haven't provided the data. If you provide the data then we should be able to help.

Comment: the link I provided can be used to look at the data